# SQL filtering a text string by unique values

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, unnest, lateral-join

My PostgreSQL database includes a column which is a text string that takes unique but unpredictable values, like so:

```
id    var
1     "A", "B"
2     "B", "C"
3     "C", "A"
4     "eggs", "toast"
5     "eggs", "bacon"
```

I need a SQL query which pulls the unique values out of `var`, like so...

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 bacon
5 eggs
6 toast
```

...but I'm not too experienced with text stuff in SQL. Help?

Comment: Is your `array` column an actual array type column?

Comment: No, it's just text. I changed the name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `regexp_split_to_table()` to split these CSV strings, and then retain the distinct values only

```
select distinct x.str
from mytable t
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t.var, ', ') x(str)
```

If you really have double quotes around the CSV elements, and you want to remove them from the results, then:

```
select distinct replace(x.str, '"', '') str
from mytable t
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t.var, ', ') x(str)
```

For the fun of it, we could also use json: surrounding the strings with square brackets make them valid json array strings, which we can then unnest with `jsonb_array_elements_text()` (an upside is that it handles the unquoting for us under the hood):

```
select distinct x.str
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text( ('[' || t.var || ']')::jsonb) x(str)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ccb4539e94fcd29939cd690885068b60)**